# How to check if user password is null or not in the database and passing that information to Vue app?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

The objective here is not to know the actual password of an user, but to know if the user has a password set or not in the database. I can distinguish the users who have passwords set, i.e. password != null, versus users who don't have passwords set, i.e. password == null, inside my Laravel controller, but when I try to pass the user list to my Vue app using an axios.get request, all passwords come up as 'undefined' even though there are users with hashed passwords in the database. The following is a sample of my Vue code:

```
axios.get('/admin/user')
  .then(function (response) {
    self.users = response.data;
    for(var i=0; i<self.users.length; i++) {
      console.log(self.users[i].password) // outputs 'undefined' for all user passwords instead of the hashed database passwords
    }
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
     // handle error
     console.log(error);
  });
```

and /admin/user from above is defined in my routes directory in web.php as:

```
Route::get('/admin/user', 'UserController@get');
```

and for the purpose of this example, my UserController@get function is defined as:

```
public function get()
    {
        $user = User::get();
        return response($user, 200);
    }
```

Any advice on how to distinguish users who have passwords set and not set would be appreciated.

Comment: That is because, if you read the [`User`](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/4f8a0f35fabd8603fb756122bf820719a259ac9b/app/Models/User.php#L32) model, you will see that it is not serializing the password to be sent...

Answer (score 1):

As @matiaslauriti mentioned in the comment, [User](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/4f8a0f35fabd8603fb756122bf820719a259ac9b/app/Models/User.php#L32) model deletes `password` field during serialization. As such you should avoid sending out passwords from your server even if they're hashed. In your particular usecase there is no need to send passwords out. You can simply check if the password is set in the backend and attach this info to the response object.

```
public function get()
    {
        $user = User::get();
        if (empty($user->password)) {
            $user->isPasswordSet = false;
        } else {
            $user->isPasswordSet = true;
        return response($user, 200);
    }
```